# Missing Riptide Reef in Oceanhorn

Tags: oceanhorn

When I finished Great Forest, I did not talk to Rigger and left and therefore I am missing the location of Riptide Reef.  I tried to go back to all the island but could not find anyone that talked to can give me Riptide Reef, any help ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a stonetomb in the cave you enter through the shrine on hermits island where you can discover the reef.

Answer (score 0):

Read the two tombstones in the Room of Answers, and you will find Riptide Reef.